# regex - Match a portion of text given begin and end of the portion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to trim a very long string that can change during time. Since it's html I can use tags and attributes name to cut it regardless of the content. unfortunately I can't find a way to write the regex match. Given the following example:

> This is (random characters) an example (random characters)

How can I match the (random characters) and "This is" using the rest, which is always the same? I've tried something along the lines of the followings:

```
^(This is)((.|\s)*an)$
```

```
This is^(?!.*(an))
```

but everything seems to fail. I think that the "any character or space in beetween" part makes the search go right to the end of the string and I miss the "an" part, but I can't figure it out how to add an exception to that.

Comment: Do you look for this `This is .*? an example .*` ?

Comment: Can this `\bThis is\b.+?(?=\ban\b)` be helpful ?

Comment: Don't do regexperiments on HTML strings

Comment: plus-one for *regexperiment* @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: both the suggestions do not match, mind that the string in between can be very long and contain white space.

Comment: You want your match to be "This is (random characters) (random characters)"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know javascript, but I will assume the following functions I will write in some loosely C-like code exist in some form:

```
string input = "This is (random characters) an example (random characters)";

string pattern = "(^This is .*) an example (.*$)";
RegexMatch match = Regex.Match( str, pattern );

string group0 = match.GetGroup(0);//this should contain the whole input
string group1 = match.GetGroup(1);//this should get the first part: This is (random characters)
string group2 = match.GetGroup(2);//this should get the second part: (random characters) at the end of the input string
```

Note: Normally in Regular Expressions, The parentheses create capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

'Look behind' would be good for this, but unfortunately, JS doesn't support it. However, you can use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and capturing groups to get the result you want.

```
let matchedGroups = new RegExp(/^This is (.+) an example (.+).$/,'g')

matchGroups.exec('This is (random characters) an example (random characters).')
```

This returns an array:

```
0:"This is (random characters) an example (random characters)."
1:"(random characters)" 
2:"(random characters)"
```

As you can see this is a little clunky, but will get you two strings that you can use.

Comment: He wants to match the "This is" part into the group too (as I understand it). You must include it in the first parentheses to achieve this.

Comment: Oh yup, @FinnTheHuman, you're right. The RegExp should be this: `let matchedGroups = new RegExp(/^(This is .+) an example (.+).$/,'g')`

Comment: . alone is not suitable because it does not include new lines, that's why I've used `(. | \n)*`. I'm working around with the regex @andrewatkinson wrote but id does not seem to work as intended. There must be some rule that I'm overlooking here because if I use <!DOCTYPE html> as my starting point and another tag like <\form> as my ending point it works, even with just `/startingPoint(.|\s)*endingPoint/` but if I try to use any other string in the body it always fail or never output. For me is also okay to match the two parts in two different times btw.